# getting a string payload to curl

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, http, curl

I am trying to curl a string payload and I need it to throw an error if it contains certain parameters.

Here is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/payload3", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json"})
    public String payloader3(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params ) throws IOException{

        @NotNull
        String type = mockendpoint.Payload3();
        return type;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your return type so that you return a `ResponseEntity`.

In the event of a successful request, you return a HTTP 200, with the required response body:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(json);
```

And in the event your parameter map size is not equal to your desired value, you can return a HTTP 400, with an appropriate error message:

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(badRequestBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consume the input as a String instead of Map(that you currently have) and do a split on it with your delimeter |. If the returned array size is not 18 then throw an exception?